# Completely replace the transformation matrix of a three.js object/mesh

Tags: javascript, matrix, three.js, transformation

## Create object

A three.js mesh object is created:

```js
    var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

    var standardMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial( {/* inputs */ } );

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, standardMaterial );

    // Then mesh is added as an object to 3D scene.
```

## Set transformation matrix

I intend to set the transformation matrix of the object:

```js
            object = ... // Is already created and passed around.

            const pkm = ... // Containing 16 numbers, equivalent of a 4x4 matrix.

            var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();

            matrix.set(
                pkm.X00, pkm.X01, pkm.X02, pkm.X03,
                pkm.X10, pkm.X11, pkm.X12, pkm.X13,
                pkm.X20, pkm.X21, pkm.X22, pkm.X23,
                pkm.X30, pkm.X31, pkm.X32, pkm.X33,
            );

            object.applyMatrix4( matrix );
            object.updateMatrixWorld( true );
```

## Problem

The problem is that the above approach of setting transformation matrix just multiplies the *new* matrix into the *previous* matrix of the object. But we want the *previous* matrix to be completely replaced by the *new* matrix.

What is the best practice - most robust way - to replace the *previous* matrix of a three.js object/mesh with a completely *new* one?

## AI chatbots

We tried some suggested solutions by AI tools offered by https://phind.com and https://poe.com. Some of them which failed are:

```js
object.matrix = matrix;
object.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
object.updateMatrixWorld(true);
```

```js
object.matrix.setFromMatrix4(matrix);
object.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
```

```js
object.matrix.copy(matrix);
object.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate = true;
```

```js
object.matrix.identity();
object.matrix.copy(newMatrix);  
object.updateMatrixWorld(true);
```

```js
object.matrix.set(pkm.X00, pkm.X01, ... )
object.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
object.updateMatrixWorld(true);
```

Comment: I don't know much about threejs, but looking at the doc (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.applyMatrix4), I see that objects expose a `matrixWorld` property. Can you just set that prop instead of "applying"?  There's also a bool called `matrixWorldNeedsUpdating` that might need to be set right after.

Comment: Maybe instead of using your own Matrix4 with `object.applyMatrix4(m)`, you could set the Object's matrix elements directly with `object.matrix.set(pkm.X00, pkm.X01, ... )`. When doing so, make sure you [disable the engine's matrix auto-update](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.matrixAutoUpdate) with `object.matrixAutoUpdate = false`

Comment: @Mr.Coder I posted an answer containing the code that works for us. Can you test and see if it works for you?

Comment: @Megidd, thank you so much for sharing the answer. But how it worked for me is, when you set a matrix manually, you actually have to turn `matrixAutoUpdate` to false and then do "not" use `updateMatrix` or  `updateMatrixWorld` on it. The matrix should be applied then with no `position.copy..` hack. Taken from here:
https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Matrix-transformations

P.S.:  I am not using Three, but the same approach applied to my engine :)

Comment: @Mr.Coder Thanks for letting me know. I'm going to share your experience with our developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

The approach commented by @Mr.Coder should work fine:

> ... how it worked for me is, when you set a matrix manually, you actually have to turn `matrixAutoUpdate` to `false` and then do "not" use `updateMatrix` or `updateMatrixWorld` on it ... Taken from here: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Matrix-transformations

## Outdated answer

Apparently, the position values of transformation matrix were the troublemaker. They have to be set manually after setting the matrix.

Apparently, the latest working code is this:

```js
object = ... // Is already created and passed around.

const pkm = ... // Containing 16 numbers, equivalent of a 4x4 matrix.

var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4(); // Creating a new matrix.

matrix.set(
    pkm.X00, pkm.X01, pkm.X02, pkm.X03,
    pkm.X10, pkm.X11, pkm.X12, pkm.X13,
    pkm.X20, pkm.X21, pkm.X22, pkm.X23,
    pkm.X30, pkm.X31, pkm.X32, pkm.X33,
);

object.applyMatrix4( matrix ); // Applying the new matrix to the object.
object.updateMatrixWorld( true );


// ** For some reason, the position has to be set separately.
// ** Not sure why.
object.position.copy( new Vector3( pkm.X03, pkm.X13, pkm.X23 ) );
```